# Angular Typescript convert file to string($byte)

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

I need to upload a file and send it as type $byte to the endpoint with POST method

First i am converting it to base64 and then from there to byte (i didn't find anywhere that I can directly convert it to byte, so maybe my point here is wrong)

**Code is in StackBlitz:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fya9mr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to convert.

The values returned by the file input element's `files` property are of type [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), which is actually a binary [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). You should be able to directly send it to the server as multipart form data:

```
saveImage(image: File): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'https://www.example.com/your-endpoint';

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', image);

    return this.http.post<any>(url, formData);
}
```

Comment: I got an error: "errors": {
    "$.VsebinaBin": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Byte[]. Path: $.VsebinaBin | LineNumber: 3 | BytePositionInLine: 4086."
    ]

Comment: As mentioned, you need to post the file as multipart form data. If your endpoint expects you to include the file in a JSON object, you have to encode your file as base64 and decode it on the server side. This is beyond the scope of Angular.

Comment: Can you show me please how to post it as multipart form data please? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nfrnii?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The relevant code is in my answer. As I said in my previous comment: if your endpoint expects you to include the file in a JSON object (as it seemingly does, based on your client-side code), you have to encode your file as base64 and decode it on the server side. This is beyond the scope of Angular.